# How can I keep my (.NET Core) Dependency Injection configuration maintainable?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` for `Dependency Injection` in `.NET Core` `Console Application`.

```
 public class Program
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
            Startup startup = new Startup();
            startup.ConfigureServices(services);

            IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var etlService = serviceProvider.GetService<IETLService>();              
        }
    }

 public class Startup
    {
        IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        public Startup()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
                Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var sqlServerConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServerConnection");

        services.AddDbContext<ETLSqlContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(sqlServerConnectionString), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddTransient<ISqlRepository, SqlRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IAzureSqlRepository, AzureSqlRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IExtractService, ExtractService>();
        services.AddTransient<ILoadService, LoadService>();
    }
 }

 public class ExtractService : IExtractService
    {
        public ISqlRepository SqlRepository { get; set; }
        public IAzureSqlRepository AzureSqlRepository { get; set; }
        public ExtractService(ISqlRepository sqlRepository, IAzureSqlRepository azureSqlRepository)
        {
            SqlRepository = sqlRepository;
            AzureSqlRepository = azureSqlRepository;
        }        
    }
```

As solution grows there will be more services for example 50+ and each service  will require registering  its `Interface` and `Implementation class` in `Startup.cs` for `Dependency Injection`. I need to know is there any better way to implement `Dependency Injection` which does not require manually adding new service `Interface` and `Implementation class` in registration code

Comment: *"Better"* is subjective

Comment: This is really an opinion based question which we consider as off-topic here I'm afraid. The default DI framework in .NET Core doesn't have anything that will help you, I would suggest using something like Autofac that lets you do much more advance DI.

Comment: You can write some extension methods on `IServiceCollection` in order to group related services together. That would make your startup.cs 'cleaner'. I would not see any reason _not_ to register dependencies this way though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chapter 12 of [Dependency Injection, Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl), Mark Seemann and I describe that there are multiple configuration options when working with a DI Container, namely:

- ***Configuration files***–Mapping are specified in configuration files (typically in XML or JSON format)
- ***`Configuration as Code`***–Code explicitly determines mappings
- ***`Auto-Registration`***–Rules are used to locate suitable components using reflection and to build the mappings.

You are currently applying `Configuration as Code`. With `Auto-Registration`, however, you apply *Convention over Configuration* to register your application components using reflection, based on a specified convention.

In section 12.3 we describe in detail when you should use a DI Container, and *how* you should use it. In summary we state that:

> The use of Convention over Configuration using `Auto-Registration` can minimize the amount of maintenance on the [`Composition Root`](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) to almost zero.

We, therefore, advice:

> a `Composition Root` should either be focused around [`Pure DI`](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) with, perhaps a few late-bound types, or around `Auto-Registration` with, optionally, a limited amount of `Configuration as Code` and configuration files. A `Composition Root` that focuses around `Configuration as Code` is pointless and should therefore be avoided.

In chapters 6 and 10 of the book, we also describe the kinds of designs you can use that, among other things, maximize convention over configuration and, with it, minimizes the amount of maintenance on your DI configuration.

Comment: For big enterprises, where composition root need to actually compose different implementations of one abstraction based on the condition - convention over configuration increase discoverability time.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by adding a class to each of my projects "PluginConfiguration", which passes in the IServiceCollection, and registers its individual services in the constructor.. Then just call each "Plugin" in the ServicesCollection in my main project. It abstracts out the config into a class thats relevant to the individual project and keeps the main config clean with just a single line of code for each additional project